# How to run lein from another directory (without cd to project dir)?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Supposing my `lein` project is located in `/some/location/project` and my current location is `/another/location/` how can I run `lein` build without changing to project location `cd /some/location/project`?

For example, in maven

```
mvn -f /path/to/pom.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell `lein` doesn't have an option like this.  You have to be in the directory.  (Perhaps someone else will correct me.)  However, you could write a shell script that does what you want.  For example, in a unix that provides the `getopts` utility, you could use the following script, which might be called "leinthere":

```
#!/bin/sh

if getopts f: option; then
    # user supplied -f
    if [ -d "$OPTARG" ]; then
        # user also supplied name of a real dir, now in $OPTARG
        cd "$OPTARG"
        shift 2 # get rid of -f and the dir name
    else
        # user supplied -f, but not a real dir name
        echo "usage: $0 [-f project-dir] [lein args]"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# now just run lein in the normal way:
lein "$@"
```

Comment: You are correct. `lein $task` looks for a `project.clj` in the current working directory.  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/d701275464c185f4f22be58450b1af4b94a79836/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/main.clj#L385